# Looping clock function using setInterval

Tags: javascript, time, settimeout, setinterval

I'm trying to create a function that can return a value (the user's current time in seconds) to another variable that can be used elsewhere in my code. The function returns the correct value, but I can't figure out how to make it repeat using `setInterval` or `setTimeout`.

```
var currenttime = clock();

function clock() {
    var now = new Date();
    var hour = now.getHours();
    var minute = now.getMinutes();
    var second = now.getSeconds();
    var time = (hour * 3600) + (minute * 60) + second;
    return time;
}

console.log(currenttime)
```

I want the variable `currenttime` to be updated every second, but changing the line to
`var currenttime = setInterval(clock, 1000);`
returns an incorrect value. Alternatively I've also tried to make the `clock` function repeat,
but I'm not sure how to do this as I'm using a return statement so the function ends before it can be repeated.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

Assign to `currentTime` every time `clock` runs, but don't `return` the `time` - since this'll be in an interval, the return value is ignored:

```js
let currentTime;

function clock() {
    var now = new Date();
    var hour = now.getHours();
    var minute = now.getMinutes();
    var second = now.getSeconds();
    currentTime = (hour * 3600) + (minute * 60) + second;
}

setInterval(clock, 1000);

setTimeout(() => console.log(currentTime), 2000);
setTimeout(() => console.log(currentTime), 6000);
```

This is a bit weird, though - variable assignment alone doesn't have side effects (in almost all cases). It would make more sense for whatever *uses* the `currentTime` variable to call `clock` to get the current number of seconds, eg:

```js
function clock() {
    var now = new Date();
    var hour = now.getHours();
    var minute = now.getMinutes();
    var second = now.getSeconds();
    return (hour * 3600) + (minute * 60) + second;
}

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('div').textContent = clock();
});
```

```html
<button>Get seconds</button>
<div id="time"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval` return only an `ID` value that can be used in `clearInterval(ID)` to stop setInterval loop.

So, you can do that:

```
function clock()
  {
  let [h,m,s] = (new Date().toTimeString()).match(/\d{2}/g)
  return (h*3600) + (m*60) + +s
  }

var currenttime = clock();
setInterval(() => { currenttime = clock() }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

The function called by setInterval should call clock and display the time.

```
setInterval(function(){ console.log(clock()); }, 1000);
```